# Difference between EMRFS S3-optimized commit protocol and EMRFS S3-optimized committer

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to improve my spark job's performance running on `EMR 6.7.0`
I usually use the below code to write to a s3 bucket

```
df.write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
  .partitionBy("dt")
  .parquet("s3://EXAMPLE-DOC-BUCKET/output")
```

I came across different documentation and I am confused.

1. [EMRFS S3-optimized commit protocol](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-commit-protocol-reqs.html)
2. [EMRFS S3-optimized committer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html)

For my use case where I use dynamically partitioned dataframe using overwrite mode, the best suited is `EMRFS S3-optimized commit protocol`. But what's the difference between the 2

I also came across another apache documentation about the Netflix's
[The “Partitioned” Staging Committer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#The_.E2.80.9CPartitioned.E2.80.9D_Staging_Committer)

What I tried in my spark job is

```
  "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name": "partitioned",
  "fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode": "replace"
```

This particular job writes 400 different partitions writing 360.5 GB in parquet. But adding the above parameters have not improved the jobs performance. It still runs the same. And the spark log still shows me this message

```
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO StagingUploadPlanner: Creating a new staged file 's3://BUCKET/execution_date=2023-03-07/year_month_day=2023-02-11/.emrfs_staging_19b8d2a3-07ea-4136-9625-e22566e27f22-134-466700/part-00134-19b8d2a3-07ea-4136-9625-e22566e27f22.c000.snappy.parquet' with destination key 'BUCKET/execution_date=2023-03-07/year_month_day=2023-02-11/part-00134-19b8d2a3-07ea-4136-9625-e22566e27f22.c000.snappy.parquet'
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO SQLConfCommitterProvider: Getting user defined output committer class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO EmrOptimizedParquetOutputCommitter: EMR Optimized Committer: ENABLED
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO EmrOptimizedParquetOutputCommitter: Using output committer class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileSystemOptimizedCommitter
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: true
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: true
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO SQLConfCommitterProvider: Using output committer class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
23/03/08 07:56:34 INFO ParquetWriteSupport: Initialized Parquet WriteSupport with Catalyst schema:
```

This is exactly same as the previous run without the partitioned committer

```
23/03/08 08:55:39 INFO StagingUploadPlanner: Creating a new staged file 's3://BUCKET/execution_date=2023-03-07/year_month_day=2022-01-20/.emrfs_staging_b96a3efa-457a-4593-8b99-3fe388cbc49e-217-267489/part-00217-b96a3efa-457a-4593-8b99-3fe388cbc49e.c000.snappy.parquet' with destination key 'BUCKET/execution_date=2023-03-07/year_month_day=2022-01-20/part-00217-b96a3efa-457a-4593-8b99-3fe388cbc49e.c000.snappy.parquet'
23/03/08 08:55:39 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
23/03/08 08:55:48 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 1215 spilling sort data of 5.1 GiB to disk (1  time so far)
23/03/08 08:55:54 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 1109 spilling sort data of 5.1 GiB to disk (1  time so far)
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO SQLConfCommitterProvider: Getting user defined output committer class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO EmrOptimizedParquetOutputCommitter: EMR Optimized Committer: ENABLED
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO EmrOptimizedParquetOutputCommitter: Using output committer class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileSystemOptimizedCommitter
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: true
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: true
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO SQLConfCommitterProvider: Using output committer class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
23/03/08 08:56:05 INFO ParquetWriteSupport: Initialized Parquet WriteSupport with Catalyst schema:
```

Questions:

1. What is the difference between the 2 s3 committers mentioned above?
2. Why there is no gain using the `Partitioned Staging Committer`? What more can I do to improve s3 write performance?

Comment: fs.s3a settings have no effect here; that's apache s3a connector, not emr

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other setting that will help me improve performance by overcoming slow s3 renaming?

Comment: s3a and emr committers don't use rename() at all, giving speed and correctness. Full details on how the OSS ones work...I haven't seen the AWS ones and given they hadn't credited our work, was fairly negative in my comments: https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases/tag/tag_release_2021-05-17